# Adding number type input field with increment disabled using css not working

Tags: html, css, input

I want an `input` field in html which will take `number input` only (`including decimal`) with increment disabled. I have used following :

```css
/* Hide Spin arrows on input type number */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="phone">
```

This works perfectly on `Google Chrome` with out any problem. But, It doesn't works on `Firefox`. Does anyone know where I am doing wrong ? Is there any other idea to get out of this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't get it, how will the css work if it targets `input` with `type="number"`, but you are using an `input` with `type="text"`?

Comment: How can you select a `text` field with `[type="number"]` selector?

Comment: @Swellar It's my typo error, I have updated

Comment: @AbhishekPandey it's my typo error I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

However, using input type='number' will never assure that numeric inputs are given in your input in firefox. you have to write a custom validation function in case of firefox. This is an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
        input[type=number] {
            -moz-appearance:textfield; /*This is for firefox*/
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        //Custom number validating function
        function isNumber(evt) {
            var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
            if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57))
                return false;

            return true;
        } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" name="phone" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber(event)">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Arrow icon not showing which is fine but it takes text as well and type number not woking

Comment: I'm using laravel framework and there is error due to other issues. Your code works perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: You are Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

i dont no why its not working on your `firebox` browser because of version or any other reasion

this code perfectly work on my both browser `firefox` and `crome`

change input type `text` to `number` first

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="phone">
```

and your css code

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Hide Spin arrows on input type number */
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
</style>
```